# How to click on an element that is in the body pragmatically from inside of an angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a website on which I have crisp chat service running and I'm trying to click on the chat box from one of my component's typescript files.

The crisp chat box is a div with the id of `crisp-client` inside `body` tag. How do I click on it from inside my typescript?

Comment: Maybe use a @ViewChild (https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/) to get your HTML Element into your Typescript file. Then just do a `this.element.click();`

Comment: @Emilien `viewChild` only works if the element is in the same component you're trying to click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject Renderer2 in constructor -

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
```

Get the crisp-client element in your component -

```
let crispClient = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#crisp-client');
```

Perform click() event -

```
crispClient.click();
```

Working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-snbgnh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Added a test method on div to check -

```
<div id="crisp-client" onClick="console.log('crisp client clicked')"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now how can I access elements that are inside the element with the crisp-client id?

Comment: Kindly refer this example, if you want to access children elements - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jtzjwf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator and pass a template reference variable as a string, and manipulate the event. Here's a simple example of clicking `Button 1`, which programmatically clicks `Button 2` and due to that click, the text of `Button 2` is changed:

```html
<button #button1 (click)="clickButton2()">
  Click to change the text of Button 2
</button>

<button #button2 (click)="changeText()">{{ buttonText }}</button>
```

```js
buttonText = 'Button 2';
  
  @ViewChild('button2') button2: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  clickButton2() {
    let el: HTMLElement = this.button2.nativeElement;
    el.click();
  }

  changeText() {
    this.buttonText="Changed!"
  }
```

[Here's a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gp7csj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**UPDATE**

You can access elements of body using `document` object in Angular. This way, you can achieve the click of the element which is inside `body`. Here's one more example where I am clicking the button which is inside `body` from a component.

```html
<button (click)="handleClick()">Programatically click the button inside body</button>
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
    let btn = document.getElementById('main');
    btn.addEventListener('click', (e: Event) => btn.innerHTML = "Clicked!");
  }

  handleClick() {
    document.getElementById('main').click();
  }
```

index.html

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <my-app>loading</my-app>
    <button id="main">Click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avdhkd?file=src/app/app.component.ts) demo.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but this only works if my button html and ts are in the same component. What if I want to access something that is in another component?

Comment: So you want to trigger a click event on an element like `component1` from `component2`?

Comment: I want to trigger a click event on one of the elements directly in body from a component.

Comment: Great. I've updated the answer. Please check

Comment: Okay but this crisp client doesn't actually exist inside my `index.html` file. It gets injected by the crisp service and I don't have access to it.

Comment: This works in any file. This checks the document and not just individual component. BTW, what's the difference between the two answers provided here?